# Navigation on webpart

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise, asp.net

I don't really got a problem just a question. After googling around I couldn't find any answer on what I'm looking for.

Is it possible to put a `<asp:TreeView/>` or multiple `<asp:LinkButton/>` so i can fastly navigate on my visual webpart?

Like this:

[image]

Hopefully i get some answers and tips here, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Since the webpart will only have one "Page" I would use some javascript / jQuery for conditionally showing and hinding different elements on the page when the user clicks one of the links (could be normal `<a>`-tags with an onclick event).

So basically you render all of your controls at once from code behind, handles the updates from code-behind but uses javascript to show the correct information based on the users link choice.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can and this person has done it, there is too much code to post:

http://dineshsharepoint.blogspot.co.uk/

obviously you would need to ammend the code! but its more to show you how he/she has done it and that it is possible! the tree view should already handle the min/max without the need of javascript / jquery

another example:

```
using (SPSite Site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url + "/UberWiki"))
{
    using (SPWeb currentWeb = Site.OpenWeb())
    {
        // set the tree view properties
        SPList list = currentWeb.GetList(currentWeb.Url+"/Lists/Pages");

        SPFieldChoice field = (SPFieldChoice)list.Fields["Categories"];
        treeView = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView();

        // Add root nodes
        foreach (string str in field.Choices)
        {
            rootNode = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode(str);
            treeView.Nodes.Add(rootNode);                        
        }

        // Add child nodes
        foreach (SPListItem rows in list.Items)
        {
            childNode = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode(rows["Title"].ToString());
            treeView.FindNode(rows["Categories"].ToString()).ChildNodes.Add(childNode);
        }
    }
    this.Controls.Add(treeView);
    base.CreateChildControls();
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832212/programmatically-creating-a-treeview-in-sharepoint-based-on-a-column

with those two examples you can easily make a treeview in a webpart that implements an ascx interface

You can also have the option of inserting the HTML direcly through code and using JS/JQ or within the button event handler that looks through the page to find the div control/ or whatever control to min/max or show/hide